# Ajax-запрос в базу данных раз в минуту

Tags: php, ajax

В базе данных есть таблица, в которой хранятся уведомления от администрации, для каждого пользователя. Требуется выводить непросмотренные уведомления в режиме реального времени используя Ajax-запрос раз в 5 минут.

Таблица `adm_notes`:

```
id | user_id | note_text | note_status
```

где `note_status` равен 1 (просмотрено) или 0 (непросмотрено).

Файл `getitems.php`:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM adm_notes WHERE note_status=0 AND user_id=ID_авторизованного_Юзера");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
if ($result[0]>0) { echo 'У вас '.$result[0].' непросмотренных уведомлений'; }
```

Код JavaScript:

```
var time = 30000;
function autoRefresh()
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "HTML",
url: "/getitems.php",
data: { а вот тут у меня проблемы... },
success: function(data){
$("#resulter").append(data);
}
});
}
setTimeout("autoRefresh()", time);
```

Как вывести уведомление в `<div id="resulter"></div>`?

Comment: Расширение `mysql` устарело, используйте `mysqli` или `pdo`

Comment: `setTimeout("autoRefresh()", time);` => `setTimeout(autoRefresh, time);` ну и в data должен объект передаваться.. `{param:"value",...}`, ну и в вашем случае (просто обновление данных) data вообще можно не прописывать

Comment: @InDevX то есть, просто без строки, где data: {...} что ли? Тогда, что он мне выведет? Все что в echo в getitems.php?

Comment: @alexashko Да, что будете отдавать то и выведет

Comment: Long Polling или WebSocket  во всей своей красе =) Откажитесь от PHP на стороне сервера, он для этой задачи не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветоал тебе посмотреть в сторону **WebSocket**, что бы не писать костыли по типу обновять каждые 5 минут...

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```

Пример взял с [api.jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Я даже боюсь посмотреть в сторону WebSocket, так как и с обычным аяксом-то не справляюсь))

Comment: Зачем использовать вебсокет если запрос раз в 5 минут проходит?

Comment: А зачем раз в 5 пинут проверять есть ли сообщения? Я так понимаю, что уведомлнения нужно показать когда администратор его отправил, а не ждать 5 минут. Хотя, я не знаю какие там потребности у сайта... В любом случае ответ я дал, с ajax data вроде помог)

Comment: действительно при высокой нагрузке аякс бы не подошел, но у меня нагрузка будет небольшая... поясните пожалуйста, в data я должен написать {result:result} получается? или что?

Comment: Смотря, что вам нужно передать в php файл. Например если вы хотите передать id_user то можете сделать вот так: data: 'id_user=51', Тогда в php файле просто берите $_GET['id_user']

Comment: с аяксом вроде все нормально, спасибо! а вот автоматическое выполнение autoRefresh() почему-то не срабатывает... не подскажете, в чем ошибка?

Comment: setTimeout позволяет вызвать функцию один раз через определённый интервал времени.
setInterval позволяет вызывать функцию регулярно, повторяя вызов через определённый интервал времени. https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval